# Count the number of consecutive occurrences in a vector

Tags: r

I have the following vector:

```
vec <- c(28, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 61, 62, 70, 71, 82, 83, 104, 105, 111, 115, 125, 136, 137, 138, 146, 147, 158, 159, 160, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 209, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 280, 283, 284, 308, 309, 318, 319, 324, 333, 334, 335, 347, 354)
```

Now I would like to get the number of consecutive occurrences in the vector of the minimum length two.
So here this would be valid for the following cases:

```
44, 45, 46, 47, 48
61, 62
70, 71
82, 83
104, 105
136, 137, 138
146, 147
158, 159, 160
185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193
263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268
283, 284
308, 309
318, 319
333, 334, 335
```

So there are 14 times cases of consecutive numbers, and I just need the integer `14` as output.

Anybody with an idea how to do that?

Comment: Did you already try something ? For instance with a `for` loop ?

Comment: Yes of course, I also checked different questions here, but could not find anything proper or similar. What should I apply with a ```for``` loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `rle` and `diff` functions :

```
a=rle(diff(vec))
sum(a$values==1)
```

Comment: In one line it is even shorter and you do not create an extra object: ```a <- sum(rle(diff(vec))$values==1)```

Answer (score 2):

`diff` and `split` will help

```
vec2 <- split(vec, cumsum(c(1, diff(vec) != 1)))
vec2[(sapply(vec2, function(x) length(x))>1)]

$`2`
[1] 44 45 46 47 48

$`3`
[1] 61 62

$`4`
[1] 70 71

$`5`
[1] 82 83

$`6`
[1] 104 105

$`10`
[1] 136 137 138

$`11`
[1] 146 147

$`12`
[1] 158 159 160

$`13`
[1] 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193

$`15`
[1] 263 264 265 266 267 268

$`17`
[1] 283 284

$`18`
[1] 308 309

$`19`
[1] 318 319

$`21`
[1] 333 334 335
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Park. When you add ```length()``` to the second line, then you get the integer ```14``` as desired. So the second line should looks something like this: ```length(vec2[(sapply(vec2, function(x) length(x))>1)])```.

Answer (score 1):

Brut force :

```
var <- sort(var)
nconsecutive <- 0
p <- length(var)-1
for (i in 1:p){
    if((var[i + 1] - var[i]) == 1){
        consecutive <- consecutive + 1
    }else{
        # If at least one consecutive number
        if(consecutive > 0){
        # when no more consecutive numbers add one to your increment
            nconsecutive = nconsecutive + 1
        }
        # Re set to 0 your increment
        consecutive <- 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another base R one-liner using `tapply` -

```
sum(tapply(vec, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(vec) != 1)), length) > 1)
#[1] 14
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the job in one line perfectly!